# Searching IP address from a CSV file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a CSV file where the columns contain several strings with IP addresses. I successfully ran the regex query but it is adding random characters in the output.

```
descr = df.loc[:, 'desc']

arr = []


pat = re.compile("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)")

for i in descr:

     test = pat.findall(i)
     arr.append(test)

df["IPA"] = arr
```

It gives IP address output, but I want the output as 10.35.50.4 etc
`[(10, 35, 50, 4)]` and `[(10, 35, 50, 3)]`.

Comment: Can you please give example input?

Comment: [131 / 0x0083] Source Name: Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS Strings: ['TCP'  '10.35.50.4:62578'] Computer Name: n-dag.com Record Number: 26242 Event Level: 4

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your groups (Anything inside a parentheses) into non-capturing groups. You can do that by adding a "?:" right after opening the parentheses.

```
pat = re.compile("(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)")
```

The reason is written on the definition of the function "findall":

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group**. Empty matches are included in the result.

Therefore it was returning all the groups, numbers inside your address, separately.

Comment: that works. But still [ and  ] are coming in the output. How can i remove that?